# Windows Authentication not working in WCF REST service from a Power BI request

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, wcf, powerbi

I'm trying to access a REST service in a WCF server from power BI using Windows Authentication.

Currently the web request from Power BI is done to a nodejs server where we can get the NTLM authentication data in the 'authorization' header of the request.

But I need to do the same request on a WCF server instead. The Rest service of the WCF is working well, when not using any authentication I can access it with the power BI request through https without any issue.

But when I activate the authentication in the WCF server (with  binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows), the request is rejected because the authentication fails. I cannot even use the NTLM data as the 'authentication' field in header is not in the received request (when authentication is not set, but I assume that's normal).

For now, everything is running on my machine, and I'm using the "Use my current credentials" option when doing the Windows authentication in Power BI. OF course there's an Active Directory.

the code in the WCF server:

```
private void StartRestServiceHosts(int port)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ServerContainerScope containerScope = new ServerContainerScope())
                {
                    RequestContext.Current.Initialize(LogAreas.Server, Shared.MainUserLogin);
                    string protocol = Shared.HttpsEnabled ? "https" : "http";
                    string uri = string.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}/Rest/", protocol, System.Environment.MachineName, port);
                    Uri httpBaseAddress = new Uri(uri);

                    var defaultWebHttpBehavior = new WebHttpBehavior()
                    {
                        AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = true,
                        DefaultBodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                        DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                        DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                        HelpEnabled = false
                    };

                    foreach (ServiceDefinition serviceDefinition in _registeredRestServices.Values)
                    {
                        string currentServiceName = serviceDefinition.Name;

                        if (!_restServiceHosts.ContainsKey(currentServiceName))
                        {
                            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceDefinition.Type,
                                new Uri(httpBaseAddress, serviceDefinition.Type.Name));


                            host.Authorization.ServiceAuthorizationManager = new PublicAuthorization();

                            Type contract = serviceDefinition.Type.GetInterface("I" + serviceDefinition.Type.Name);
                            ServiceEndpoint endPoint = new ServiceEndpoint(
                                ContractDescription.GetContract(contract),
                                _restBinding,
                                new EndpointAddress("{0}{1}".FormatWith(uri, contract.Name))
                            );

                            endPoint.Behaviors.Add(defaultWebHttpBehavior);
                            endPoint.Behaviors.Add(new CorsSupportBehavior());

                            host.AddServiceEndpoint(endPoint);

                            _restServiceHosts.Add(currentServiceName, host);
                        }

                        // Open 
                        if (_restServiceHosts[currentServiceName].State != CommunicationState.Opened)
                        {
                            _restServiceHosts[currentServiceName].Open();
                        }
                    }

                    OnWcfRestServicesStarted?.Invoke(null, true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnWcfRestServicesStarted?.Invoke(null, false);
            }
        }

public WebHttpBinding CreateWebHttpBinding(string name)
    {
        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = Shared.HttpsEnabled ? WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport : WebHttpSecurityMode.None;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        //binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
        binding.Name = name;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
        binding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;

        return binding;
    }

  <appSettings>
    <add key="HttpsEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Any ideas as to why the authentication is not working?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Maybe you can use wsHttpBinding with username authentication and TransportWithMessageCredentials.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff648840(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Ok, it's working fine when using localhost or the ip of the machine to connect, but doesn't when I'm connecting using the domain name. So the code is probably ok, and the issue may be from some config on our network.